# GitHub push to Azure website

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-roles

I have a GitHub repo that I want Azure to monitor for changes and get latest when it is updated.  I am at the point in the Deployments tab where I can "Associate a GitHub Repository".  When I click the "Authorize Windows Azure" link, a dialog pops and some of my repos are available, but the repo I want to publish is not listed.

What drives the repos that appear in this dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only public repositories are supported at the moment (this might change soon).